# Does Little Steven only appear after fighting Steve?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

The first time I defeated Steve, I got a message that said "Little Steven (the item) has appeared in the basement". Since then, I've only ever found Little Steven after defeating the boss Steve. Is he an item that can only be found under this particular circumstance or can he appear randomly in the basement?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if he can appear randomly (I think he can, but not 100%) but I know for sure you can roll him with the D6 anywhere, but I think that's a bit different, as you can roll almost anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little Steve can be found as a rare drop in any item room (or shop, or it can be rolled off of any other item with the D6) once he has been unlocked.

Steven also drops Little Steve when he is killed, most of the time (I think it's about a 90% chance).

If you already have Little Steve when you kill Steven, he will instead drop the buff item "Steven". He will also rarely drop "Steven" even if you don't have Little Steve.

Finally, here is some photographic evidence:
[image: Little Steven in item room]

Comment: This holds true for similar items as well (little Gish, little Chad). Also, if I remember correctly, once unlocked, these items have start appearing in shops as well.

Comment: @Aubergine Yes that is correct, I forgot about shops, I'll add it in.

Answer (score 0):

From: [bindingofisaac wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Items)

> "Little Steve
>
> Follows Isaac around shooting homing projectiles. Rolling Little Steve with the D6 from the boss fight with Steve can give Steven.
>
> Unlocked by killing Steve alternate boss, also dropped by him."

So yes, you have to kill Steve first. It does not mention any other way but rolling D6, which is different. So I would assume that that is the only way since wiki's generally seem very thorough.

He can be found there after killing Steven, but no sooner.

Comment: The question is whether killing Steven is the only way to get little Steve (or if he can also be found randomly), not whether you have to kill Steven to unlock little steve.

Comment: It says no other alternative, so I was hoping you could infer that yes it is the only way...

Comment: Killing Steve unlocks Little Steve. From then on, Little Steve can be found at random, can't he? That's what the question is asking.

Comment: I'm more curious about the "also dropped by him part." Does that mean indefinitely or only after the first defeat? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: To that, I have no idea. Sorry.